# proxy settings for terminal ubuntu

Tags: command-line, proxy

I am trying to set proxy settings for ubuntu terminal in order to download packages. I created a file in /etc/apt/apt.conf with the following values:

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://jim\@example.com:123456@proxy.example.:8080/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://jim\@example.com:123456@proxy.example.:8080/";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://jim\@example.com:123456@proxy.example.:8080/";
Acquire::socks::proxy "socks://jim\@example.com:123456@proxy.example.:8080/";
```

Is this correct or I need to write it differently because my username is an email? Do I need to set settings in some other location also?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you really have to put `@example.com` in the username? Can't you omit it?

Comment: Νο Ι I cant...It is a proxy server which requires username and password in the above format..

Answer (score 0):

If you have an `@example.com` in your username, then you should [%-encode (or URL-encode)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_reserved_characters) the `@`, just like you would encode special characters in your password. Like so:

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://jim%40example.com:123456@proxy.example.:8080/";
```